# How can I Toggle "Autolocking of Layers" without accessing "Layer Specials" Menu (Blender 2.92.0)?

Tags: grease-pencil, dopesheet

I'm experiencing a lot of tedium while animating with Blender Grease Pencil because I do not yet have an efficient workflow. I'm wondering if there is a hotkey, or if not, a way to easily create one, to instantly access the "Autolock Inactive Layers" menu item under the "Layer Specials" dropdown which can be found under the **Object Data** tab in the **Properties Panel**. It is a toggle behavior, so only one key would be needed. I get the impression that this Layer Specials menu might not exist in previous versions of Blender, so please take note of the version I'm using (2.92.0).

[image]

An alternative solution might be to have a faster way to instantly turn on or off the editability of every single channel in the **Grease Pencil Dope Sheet**. I find it rather insufferable that I must currently scrub with the mouse to get the entire list of channels to be made editable or not editable. It seems there should be a single master toggle icon at the very top of this list that would effect all channels at once.

[image]

I never felt the need for a solution to this problem until working with Grease Pencil in earnest. One is often needing to switch the behavior between having the editability of non-active layers on or off. This is especially the case because of the need to sometimes have strokes and fills from the same object on different layers, where manipulating the two elements at the same time will require inactive layer editability to be on, while manipulating them separately will require it to be off. I find it tedious to access the "Layer Specials" menu by mouse, especially when it will often be the case that the Object Data tab is not the one currently open in the Properties Panel.

Thanks for any suggestions on this. My progress will depend on finding a better way.

Answer (score 0):

While I was just about to post this question, a possible answer dawned on me. If you right-click the "Autolock Inactive Layers" option from the "Layer Specials" menu, you can add the function to **Quick Favorites**. I completely forgot about that option! This is great for getting me through at the moment. But I'd still like to know if there is another solution.